# problems about map STL

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

```
void huffmanDecode(string str){

string temp;
map<string, char>::iterator it;
//for(auto iter=myMap.begin();iter!=myMap.end();++iter)
    //cout<<iter->first<<" "<<iter->second<<" "<<endl;

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
{
    temp += str[i];
    it = myMap.find(temp);
    if (it == myMap.end())
        continue;
    else
    {
        cout<<it->first<<" ";//crashed here, "Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x0)
        //cout << it->second << " ";
        temp = nullptr;
    }
}
}
```

I am trying solving the huffmandecode problem by map ,but it crashed ~~~

Comment: You really don't want to be doing this: `temp = nullptr;`. That is probably the reason for the crash.

Comment: I'll try it.Then how about temp=NULL;?

Comment: @ScottLangham You probably meant `temp.clear()`.

Comment: `NULL` would give you the same problem. Read up on the `std::string` documentation. You can say `temp = "";` or `temp.clear()` or `temp = std::string();`.

Comment: @Paul yes, i was fixing while you commented :)

Comment: perfect! It's sloved. But why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::string::operator=`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D) has an overload that takes a `const char*`. This is the overload that is used when you say

```
temp = nullptr;
```

Now, a requirement is that the `const char*` point to a [null-terminated string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string). Thus it cannot be the null pointer. You are not allowed to pass a null pointer, and an implementation is allowed to raise an exception in this case. In any case, attempting to use such a string would result in *undefined behaviour*. There is an analogous situation with the `std::string` constructor.

If your intention was to re-set `temp` to be an empty string, you have a few options:

```
temp = "";
temp.clear();
temp = std::string();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have defined `temp` as a `std::string`, not as a *pointer*.
So setting it to `nullptr` is wrong!

If you want to clear its contents, which I assume you actually want to, try this:

```
temp.clear();
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't explain anything though.

Comment: @juanchopanza I suppose the OP needed help regarding the crash!